# envoy external process sample with dot net grpc service

Tags: .net, envoyproxy

static_resources:

listeners:

- address:
  socket_address:
  address: 0.0.0.0
  port_value: 10000
  filter_chains:

  - filters:

    - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
      typed_config:
      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
      codec_type: AUTO
      stat_prefix: ingress_http
      route_config:
      name: local_route
      virtual_hosts:
      - name: backend
      domains:
      - "*"
      typed_per_filter_config:
      envoy.filters.http.cors:
      '@type': "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.cors.v3.CorsPolicy"
      allow_origin_string_match:
      - safe_regex:
      regex: *
      allow_methods: 'GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS'
      allow_headers: >-
      hmac,DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,total
      allow_credentials: true
      max_age: '1728000'
      routes:
      - match:
      prefix: "/WeatherForecast"
      route:
      cluster: service1
      response_headers_to_add:
      - header:
      key: Access-Control-Expose-Headers
      value: '*'
      http_filters:

      - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
        typed_config:
        '@type': "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.cors.v3.Cors"
      - name: envoy.filters.http.ext_proc
        typed_config:
        '@type': "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.ext_proc.v3.ExternalProcessor"
        failure_mode_allow: false
        async_mode: false

        allow_mode_override: true
        processing_mode:
        request_header_mode: "SEND"
        response_header_mode: "SKIP"
        request_body_mode: "NONE"
        response_body_mode: "NONE"
        request_trailer_mode: "SKIP"
        response_trailer_mode: "SKIP"

        grpc_service:
        envoy_grpc:
        cluster_name: grpc
      - name: envoy.filters.http.router
        typed_config:
        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router

clusters:

- name: grpc
  type: STATIC
  connect_timeout: 0.25s
  http2_protocol_options: {}
  load_assignment:
  cluster_name: grpc
  endpoints:

  - lb_endpoints:

    - endpoint:
      address:
      socket_address:
      address: 172.21.32.1
      port_value: 6666
- name: service1
  type: STRICT_DNS
  lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
  load_assignment:
  cluster_name: service1
  endpoints:

  - lb_endpoints:

    - endpoint:
      address:
      socket_address:
      address: 172.21.32.1
      port_value: 5017
- name: service_petstore_io
  type: LOGICAL_DNS
  dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
  load_assignment:
  cluster_name: service_petstore_io
  endpoints:
  - lb_endpoints:
  - endpoint:
  address:
  socket_address:
  address: petstore.swagger.io
  port_value: 443
  transport_socket:
  name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
  typed_config:
  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
  sni: petstore.swagger.io

i want grpc service that can be call using this envoy in dot net core how i can create that?